# Android studio how to set time for countdown

Tags: android, performance

hi guys so i got a code for a countdown but the time set is only for 30 seconds and i need to make it for at least 1 minute.... what value should i change to make it 1 minute? here are the codes i use

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            tvTimer.setText("Time remaining : " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Results.class);
            in.putExtra("passedCorrect", correct);
            in.putExtra("passedWrong", wrong);
            in.putExtra("passedMark", marks);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Generally a [search like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=countdowntimer+android) will take you directly to the class documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes this line:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
```

to:

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000)
```

The first argument in the Constructor is asking how long to wait (in milliseconds) between runs.